# Retrieve SQL queries generated with Room Android

Tags: android, android-room, dao

How to retrieve all the SQL `queries` generated by [Room Android](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data)?

**My Dao class:**

```java
@Dao
public interface MyDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE age > :minAge")
    public User[] loadAllUsersOlderThan(int minAge);
}
```

I want to retrieve the content of `@Query` annotation.

I know I can use an annotation processor but this does not allow me to retrieve the queries used to create database tables and the one generated from `@Insert`, `@Update`, and `@Delete`.

I want to reuse those queries in another app with [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) in `Node.JS`.

**Edit:**

I want to retrieve the `queries` programmatically to prevent writing them twice, once for the android app and once again for the `Node.JS` app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody else wants to export all queries automatically, what I have done instead of getting them manually in each of my **DaoClassName**_Impl is to export my room database schema then processing the json file exported. If you want to create a java module in android studio for easy reuse, I suggest to create an annotation processor *(even if it does not process any annotation)* that will run automatically every time you build your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the queries via the generated code *yourDao*(s) suffixed with **_impl** and *your@DatabaseClass(s)* also suffixed with **_impl**

e.g. For

```
@Dao
public interface CustomerDao {

    @Insert
    long insert(Customer customer);

    @Query("INSERT INTO Customer (firstname, lastName, dateAdded) VALUES(:firstName,:lastName,:dateAdded)")
    long insert(String firstName, String lastName, String dateAdded);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE firstName=:firstName AND lastName = :lastName")
    Customer getCustomerByName(String firstName, String lastName);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM customer")
    LiveData<List<Customer>> getAllCustomers();
}
```

then **CustomerDao_Impl** is :-

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "deprecation"})
public final class CustomerDao_Impl implements CustomerDao {
  private final RoomDatabase __db;

  private final EntityInsertionAdapter<Customer> __insertionAdapterOfCustomer;

  private final SharedSQLiteStatement __preparedStmtOfInsert;

  public CustomerDao_Impl(RoomDatabase __db) {
    this.__db = __db;
    this.__insertionAdapterOfCustomer = new EntityInsertionAdapter<Customer>(__db) {
      @Override
      public String createQuery() {
        return "INSERT OR ABORT INTO `Customer` (`id`,`firstName`,`lastName`,`dateAdded`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
      }
  ..........
```

and for **ShopDatabase**

```
@Database(entities = {Customer.class}, version = 1)
//@TypeConverters({Converters.class})
public abstract class ShopDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static ShopDatabase instance;
    ..........
```

then **ShopDatabase_Impl** is :-

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "deprecation"})
public final class ShopDatabase_Impl extends ShopDatabase {
  private volatile CustomerDao _customerDao;

  @Override
  protected SupportSQLiteOpenHelper createOpenHelper(DatabaseConfiguration configuration) {
    final SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback _openCallback = new RoomOpenHelper(configuration, new RoomOpenHelper.Delegate(1) {
      @Override
      public void createAllTables(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Customer` (`id` INTEGER, `firstName` TEXT, `lastName` TEXT, `dateAdded` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))");
        _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)");
        _db.execSQL("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO room_master_table (id,identity_hash) VALUES(42, '588832abfd9fd9c6aad8dcebe485e219')");
      }

      @Override
      public void dropAllTables(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Customer`");
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
          for (int _i = 0, _size = mCallbacks.size(); _i < _size; _i++) {
            mCallbacks.get(_i).onDestructiveMigration(_db);
          }
        }
      }
      ..........
```

- your would probably not want the room_master_table as that is room specific and the hash is generated, I believe, from the code so is sensitive to changes being made.

  - where .......... indicates code omitted for brevity